# Find Dates and Sum

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm stumped. I'm currently trying to create a time off tracker for time off.

I have two tabs.

First tab: "Overview" - This tab has three columns.

- Month
- Amt Used

  ```
  =SUMIFS(Data!$C:$C,Data!$A:$A,"January")
  ```

  This formula access the data tab, and uses the first column information and sums the amount for that month.
- Amt Left
  Jan

  ```
  =B5+$G$4
  ```

  Feb

  ```
  =C5+B6+$G$4
  ```

  This adds the amount left, with amount used and adds the accrual rate with it each month.

Then to the right, I have "Accrual Rate" and the cell next to it is variable. It is the place to put the amount of hours accrued in a month. (The forumla will multiple it by 12 months to simplify for the user)

Done with first tab.

Second tab: Called "Data"

This is where one can put their days off.

This is nothing fancy. Three untitled columns.

- a cell with a formula:

  ```
  =IF(B1="","",TEXT(B1,"mmmmmmmm"))
  ```
- Next column is the date in mm/dd/yyyy format.
- Next column is the amount of hours used. Negative for "using hours" and positive number for "gaining hours".

Now, maybe I did not need a long explantion to ask this question. I'm trying to remove the column that figures out the month. Is there a way to use the Sumif command to find by date within the formula?

If the dates are:

1/1/2013 | -8 |

1/2/2013 | -8 |

1/3/2013 | -8 |

1/4/2013 | -8 |

2/2/2013 | -8 |

2/3/2013 | -8 |

2/4/2013 | -8 |

Is there a way to say, if the month is "1" or Jan, sum the total of the cell next to it? In this case, the answer should be 32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SUMIFS you could sum between 1st and 31st Jan, e.g.

`=SUMIFS(Data!$C:$C,Data!$B:$B,">="&DATE(2013,1,1),Data!$B:$B,"<="&DATE(2013,1,31))`

or probably better to reference a cell with the date, so say you have 1st Jan 2013 in B3 in Overview tab that would be:

`=SUMIFS(Data!$C:$C,Data!$B:$B,">="&B3,Data!$B:$B,"<="&EOMONTH(B3,0))`

The latter formula can be copied down for multiple months

Comment: =SUMIFS(Data!$C:$C,Data!$B:$B,">="&DATE(2013,1,1),Data!$B:$B,"<="&DATE(2013,1,31))

Comment: Thanks for quick and to the point. I am accepting after this comment!